# Custom Attribute's Value Null at Frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, custom-attributes

I am new with Magento. Now I'm using **magento 1.9**
So I add new attribute for my products via **backend magento admin**. I already assigned that attribute to my product's Attribute sets.
the attribute code is 
**full_bertahap_price**
It appeared at edit product page. And the value can saved. No problem at all
[image]

But when I try to get the attribute's value in **Frontend**, it returned NULL.
this is my code

```
<?php
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cart = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();   
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($cart as $_item): ?>

        <?php  
             $the_item = $_item;
        ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <?php 

            $value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($the_item->getProductId());

            echo $value->getFullBertahapPrice();    ?>
```

I try to use

```
Zend_Debug::dump($value->getFullBertahapPrice());
```

And the result is

```
NULL
```

Can someone help me to solve this? Where I went wrong? In the admin backend that attribute has value but in Frontend its NULL?
Please help !

> Edit : My cache is disabled and I also already Reindex Data but
>   nothing work.

Comment: just print this `$the_item->getProductId()` check and add result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```
$value->getData('full_bertahap_price');
```

or use this

```
$the_item->getProduct()->getId()
```

instead of

```
$the_item->getProductId()
```

try this also

```
$attribute = $value->getResource()->getAttribute('full_bertahap_price');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($value);
}
```

May be it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it still not working. Still got NULL for the result. and I try print getProductId() just like you said and it show the ID of the product.
I don't get it, why backend can get the value but frontend can't? Does backend used different database or different approach?

Comment: try to print `$value->getData()` and check your attribute is there or not?

Comment: I try to use Zend_Debug again and it show arrays. I try to find it with ctrl+f and it shown 15 matches of full_bertahap_price. I try to track it and one of them shown array ["full_bertahap_price"] => object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute)#249 (22) 
it inside an array tho.
It's on the deeper array not like other attributes like price that on the first dimension of array. So it's detected or not?

Comment: try this `$attribute = $value->getResource()->getAttribute('full_bertahap_price');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($value);
}`

Comment: nope. nothing showing. so the attribute is not there?

Comment: yes.. and also check backend attribute configuration

Comment: I see. Which configuration that I must check? 'Scope' on Website, 'Apply to' All Product Types, and 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end' is on Yes. Any other configurations?

Comment: Which type you have use for this attribute?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't really get it. What do you mean by which type I have use?

Comment: `input type` like integer, multiselect, etc?

Comment: Oh. it's text field

Comment: try to flush cache from admin

Comment: nope. not working. Still null. and I already disabled the caches.
Any chance that I can't make this custom attributes using backend admin? I must using module or something else?

Comment: try to get default attribute value

Comment: I am sorry, but how you get default attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your code inside the `foreach` loop, It may be multiple item in your cart.

```
<?php
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cart = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();   
?>
<div class="row">
<?php 
foreach($cart as $_item): 
    $the_item = $_item;
    $value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($the_item->getProductId());
    echo $value->getFullBertahapPrice();
endforeach 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Ashish, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @user2290559, If its not working then you have to check first its available in product or not with print_r($value->getData()). If Not available then update product in admin again and do Reindex.

Comment: It can be found inside other array but it can't be found on the 1st dimension like price or sku attribute. In the admin full_bertahap_price has the value that I input earlier (like in the pic that I post) and I also already reindex data also clear all cache via magento although I already disabled it and manually delete var/cache. But it still not shown on front end.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works !!
I don't really know how I done it actually.
I turn ON the Use Flat Catalog Product in Setting Configuration
Then I Reindex Flat Data
and then I use this code

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($the_item->getProduct()->getId())->getFullBertahapPrice();
```

and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you a better solution. Here it is :

```
<?php
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cart  = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();   
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        foreach ($cart as $_item) :  
            echo $_item->getProduct()->getFullBertahapPrice();
        endforeach; 
    ?>
</div>
```

#### Why should use this?

1. You need to echo your attribute value within `foreach` loop. This is because, it is possible to have more than one product available in cart
2. Better use `getProduct()` call on quote item. This may avoid forceful model load in most of the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rajeev. Really useful information